# Extracting some daily parameter of points from era5 land hourly in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I tried to extract a station dataset with configuration similar to station observation data, but my code is stuck and failed to give me the CSV file that I want. I couldn't find where I missed.

```
var roi_list = [
{point:ee.Geometry.Point(108.53904,-6.7553),StationID:'Station1'},
{point:ee.Geometry.Point(107.59733,-6.88356),StationID:'Station2'},
{point:ee.Geometry.Point(106.75,-6.5),StationID:'Station3'},
{point:ee.Geometry.Point(106.85,-6.7),StationID:'Station4'},
{point:ee.Geometry.Point(106.84,-6.15559),StationID:'Station5'},
{point:ee.Geometry.Point(108.263,-6.7344),StationID:'Station6'},
{point:ee.Geometry.Point(109.12103,-6.86817),StationID:'Station7'}]
var StudyArea = geometry;
Map.addLayer(StudyArea);
Map.centerObject(StudyArea);

roi_list.forEach(function(roi)  {
  var startDate = '2017-12-01'
  var endDate = '2023-01-01'
  function calculateE(temp) {
    return ee.Number.expression(
      'E0 * exp((L_Rv) * ((1 / T0) - (1 / (temp))))', {
        E0: 0.611, // kPa
        L_Rv: 5423, // K
        T0: 273, // K
        K: 273.15,
        temp: temp
      }
    )
  }    
  var ic = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
    .select(['dewpoint_temperature_2m', 'temperature_2m'])
    .filterBounds(StudyArea)
  var collection = ic.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  var rhCollection = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst('hour_8')
    .apply({
      primary: collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hour', 2)), 
      secondary: collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('hour', 8)), 
      condition: ee.Filter.maxDifference({
        difference: 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
        leftField: 'system:time_start', 
        rightField: 'system:time_start'
      })
    }))
    .map(function (hour2) {
      var hour8 = ee.Image(hour2.get('hour_8'))
      var reduced = hour2.rename(['tempd9', 'temp9'])
        .addBands(hour8.rename(['tempd15', 'temp15']))
        .reduceRegion({
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
          geometry: roi.point, 
          scale: 10,
          maxPixels: 1e13
        })
            var temp9 = reduced.getNumber('temp9')
      var tempd9 = reduced.getNumber('tempd9')
      var temp15 = reduced.getNumber('temp15')
      var tempd15 = reduced.getNumber('tempd15')
      var E9 = calculateE(ic.select('temperature_2m').filterDate(hour2.date(), ee.Date(hour2.date()).advance(1, "day")).first())
      var Es9 = calculateE(ic.select('dewpoint_temperature_2m').filterDate(hour2.date(), ee.Date(hour2.date()).advance(1, "day")).first())
      var E15 = calculateE(ic.select('temperature_2m').filterDate(hour8.date(), ee.Date(hour8.date()).advance(1, "day")).first())
      var Es15 = calculateE(ic.select('dewpoint_temperature_2m').filterDate(hour8.date(), ee.Date(hour8.date()).advance(1, "day")).first())
      var RH9 = E9.divide(Es9).multiply(100)
      var RH15 = E15.divide(Es15).multiply(100)
      return ee.Feature(null, {
        date: hour2.date().format('dd-MM-yyyy'),
        Temp9: temp9.subtract(273.15),
        TempD9: tempd9.subtract(273.15),
        Temp15: temp15.subtract(273.15),
        TempD15: tempd15.subtract(273.15),
        E9: E9,
        Es9: Es9,
        RH9: RH9,
        RH15: RH15,
      })})
  var dates = ee.List.sequence(0, 1856).map(function(day){
    return ee.Date.fromYMD(2017,12,01,'Asia/Jakarta').advance(day, "day");
  });
  var res = dates.map(function(date){
            var image = ic.select('temperature_2m').filterDate(date, ee.Date(date).advance(1, "day"));
            var b = ee.Image(273.15);
            var min = image.min();
            var min1 = min.clip(StudyArea);
            var max = image.max();
            var max1 = max.clip(StudyArea);
            var a = ee.Image(2);   
            var sum = max1.add(min1);
            var avg = sum.divide(a);
            var celcius = avg.subtract(b);
            var c = ee.Image(0)
            var gdd = celcius.subtract(c).rename('Dailytemp');
            var gdd_reduced = gdd.reduceRegion({
                 reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                 geometry: roi.point,
                 scale: 10
                }).get("Dailytemp");
            var min_temp = min1.subtract(b).reduceRegion({
                 reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                 geometry: roi.point,
                 scale: 10
                }).get("temperature_2m");
            var max_temp = max1.subtract(b).reduceRegion({
                 reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                 geometry: roi.point,
                 scale: 10
                }).get("temperature_2m");
            return ee.Feature(null, {
              'date': ee.Date(date).advance(1, "day").format('dd-MM-yyyy'),
              'Dailytemp': gdd_reduced,
              'MinTemp': min_temp,
              'MaxTemp': max_temp,
              })});  
    //print(ee.FeatureCollection(res))    

  var ic2 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
  .select(['total_precipitation_hourly'])
  .filterBounds(StudyArea)
  var dates = ee.List.sequence(0, 1856).map(function(day){
    return ee.Date.fromYMD(2017,12,01,'Asia/Jakarta').advance(day, "day");
  });
  var res2 = dates.map(function(date){
            var image = ic2.filterDate(date, ee.Date(date).advance(1, "day"));
            var total = image.sum();
            var total = total.clip(StudyArea);
            var a = ee.Image(1000);
            var totalmm = total.multiply(a).rename('DailyP');
            var totalmm_reduced = totalmm.reduceRegion({
                 reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                 geometry: roi.point,
                 scale: 10
                }).get("DailyP");
            return ee.Feature(null, {
              'date': ee.Date(date).advance(1, "day").format('dd-MM-yyyy'),
              'DailyP': totalmm_reduced
              })});
  res2 = ee.FeatureCollection(res2).map(function (feature) {
    var dailyP = ee.Number(feature.get('DailyP'));
    var modifiedDailyP = ee.Algorithms.If(dailyP.lt(1), 0, dailyP);
    return feature.set('DailyP', modifiedDailyP);
  });
  var merger1 = ee.Join.inner().apply({
    primary: ee.FeatureCollection(res),
    secondary: rhCollection,
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: 'date',
      rightField: 'date'
    })
  });
  var merger2 = merger1.map(function(feature) {
    return ee.Feature(feature.get('primary')).copyProperties(feature.get('secondary'));
  });
  var merger3 = ee.Join.inner().apply({
    primary: merger2,
    secondary: res2,
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: 'date',
      rightField: 'date'
    })
  });
  var merger = merger3.map(function(feature) {
    return ee.Feature(feature.get('primary')).copyProperties(feature.get('secondary'));
  });
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: merger,
    description: 'TRHP_'+ roi.StationID,
    fileNamePrefix: roi.StationID +"_P_T_RH_ERA5",
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Station TRHP',
    selectors: ['date', 'Dailytemp','MinTemp','MaxTemp', 'RH9', 'RH15','DailyP']
  })
})
```

The error I got is

> Error: Error in map(ID=20171201T02): Number.divide, argument 'right': Invalid type. Expected type: Number. Actual type: Image<[temperature_2m]>. (Error code: 3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in res variable. To use math operations like divide, multiply a constant with an image, it has to be done directly do this without conversion.

```
var avg = sum.divide(2)
```

Likewise, you need to change other operations for b and c.